# Examples of shapes that do not possess translational symmetry

Tags: geometry, surfaces, curvature, symmetry

I thought that all shapes possess translational symmetry, as simply moving it shouldn't change the shape. Then I thought of a situation where it does, though it contains three criteria.

1. The observer is fixed.
2. The shape does not possess reflective symmetry.
3. The shape is moved on a curved surface.

An easy-to-visualize example of this would be a moon shape being moved on the surface of a sphere. If it was moved halfway around the sphere, it would be flipped from the perspective of the observer (this is assuming the observer can see through the sphere).

However, is this a valid situation? If not, what examples are there of shapes that do not have translational symmetry? I cannot see how there can ever be an example of a shape without translational symmetry on a flat plane.

**EDIT:** This question is based on a misunderstanding of translational symmetry, my understanding coming from this site: https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/symmetry/

Comment: Translational symmetry doesn't mean what you seem to think. If you look at a circle (for example) in the plane and close your eyes while I move the circle, then when you open your eyes you can see that something is *different* from before (the circle has *moved*!), so this example does *not* have translational symmetry. In order to have that, everything must look indistinguishable from what it did before you closed your eyes, which in particular means that the shape cannot be bounded.

Comment: For simplicity, let's imagine we are in $\mathbb R^3$. The example you're describing is a translation on the sphere, but not a translation in $\mathbb R^3$ - it has undergone a rotation. However, the transformation you've described is an isometry (in both the sphere and $\mathbb R^3$) since it has not been distorted in any way - only moved.

Comment: @HansLundmark https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/symmetry/ This site says that translational symmetry is whenever a shape is unchanged by movement. Is the site wrong, or did I misunderstand it? Also, if a shape exists on the surface of a sphere, and it is moved all the way around the sphere back to the same place. Would that be a translational symmetry? If so, there'd be infinitely many translational symmetries for a shape on a spherical manifold.

Comment: @JackT But it has been distorted though, hasn't it? It has been rotated. Also, aren't all symmetry operations isometric transformations?

Comment: @ChemLad: The explanation on that page was very unclear indeed! The picture doesn't even seem to illustrate a translation (since the three objects are clearly not aligned along a straight line), much less a translational *symmetry*... See Wikipedia instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translational_symmetry

Comment: And the claim “translation symmetry is defined as the sliding of an object about an axis” is just plain wrong. With some good will, that could be interpreted as a definition of a **translation**, but it says nothing about **symmetry**.

Comment: @HansLundmark I see. How about the shape moving around the sphere? If it moved all the way around, arriving at the exact same place, wouldn't that be a translational symmetry? Or, would that be its identity R$_0$, since it is taking a full rotation?

Comment: I would say that it wouldn't count, since it's really the identity mapping that you're applying to the object.

Comment: The only way for a shape to feature translational symmetry is to be periodic, with the period being the translation vector. This implies that the shape has infinite extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, "translation" refers to Euclidean spaces like $\Bbb R^2$ (plane) or $\Bbb R^3$, the 3-space.

"Translational symmetry" then means you can move an object, and it still looks the same.  Moving a moon across a plane or across a sphere$^1$, the moon looks different: it's in a different place and you can tell apart "before" and "after" the move (except the move was trivial, i.e. a no-move).

An example of an "object" that has translational symmetry is the set of intergers in $\Bbb R$: Moving all integers one unit to the right, you still get all integers and the set remains unchanged.  The natural numbers, however, are not invariant under translation.

---

**Notes**

$^1$Defining translation in other spaces is a bit tricky, because it should be possible to move objects around to start with.  For example, you cannot move a piece of flat fabric that's flexible but does not stretch, from a flat part of a space to a place where the space is bumpy: The fabric will wrinkle and the concept of "moving objects around" will fall apart.

You can still extend the concept to other spaces, though, provided the space has constant (non-changing) curvature everywhere.  Examples are

- The Euclidean space (flat, infinite in size).
- The [Hyperbolic plane and space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_manifold) can be assigned a constant negative curvature (infinite).
- The [n-Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) with constant positive curvature (finite).
- [n-Torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Finite_dimensional_torus) (flat, finite), however there is no nice isometric embedding in 3-space.  Common example of a flat 2-torus is a flat computer screen where a player enters the screen again at the bottom when he leaves it at the top etc.
- Finite hyperbolic spaces with constant negative curvature like a bretzel (finite).  Same problem with isometric embeddings like with the n-torus.
- Specific combinations of the objects above.  For example the surface of a cylinder (flat, infinite).

Examples of translational invariant objects in hyperbolic space are [hyperbolic tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane).

Examples of translational invariant objects on a 2-sphere are implied by the [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) ("blow" them up so the faces lie on a sphere) and also by tilings that have $m$-fold rotational symmetry like a latitudes + longitudes coordinate grid.